# Laravel Nova - Display name for relationship on update

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I have a recursive relationship, where model `Question` has one to many relationship to table itself. Column `parent_question_id` will refer to `id` in `questions` table.

In `Question model` :

```
/**
 * Get the parent that owns the question.
 */
public function parent()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Question', 'parent_question_id');
}
```

In `Question resource` :

```
public function fields(Request $request)
{
    return [
        BelongsTo::make('Parent', 'parent', '\App\Nova\Question'),
        ...
    ];
}
```

Above code displays `Question`, instead of `Parent` on update. It is ok on index & detail pages.

[image]

Is there any function I can use to update the display name value for field ?

Laravel Nova version - 1.0.16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried setting `label` & didn't work. But setting `singularLabel` works for me.

```
BelongsTo::make('Parent', 'parent', '\App\Nova\Question')
                ->withMeta(['singularLabel' => 'Parent']),
```

**Update**

The issue is no longer in v1.1.7